# How can I store and update database result in redis cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

After querying a database, I get an array of objects I have called queryResult. How can I:

1. Store the array of objects in a redis cache?
2. Update the redis cache as the database keeps getting populated?

Here is an example of what queryResult may look like:

```
const queryResult=[
{
  username: 'name1',
  prop1: 'some string',
  prop2: 'another string',
  prop3: 'another string 2'
},
{
  username: 'name2',
  prop1: 'some string',
  prop2: 'another string',
  prop3: 'another string 2'
},
{
  username: 'name3',
  prop1: 'some string',
  prop2: 'another string',
  prop3: 'another string 2'
},...
]
```

I have tried to use `get`,`hget`,`set`,`hmset` etc but they didn't work. Here is the last thing I tried:

**Cache Middleware**

```
function cache(req, res, next) {
    const { username } = req.params;

    client.get(username, (err, data) = {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(data !== null){
        return res.send(setResponse(username, JSON.parse(data)));
    }
    next();
})
}

// controller/function handler
async function getRepos(req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log('fetching...');
        const { username } = req.params;
        const resp = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

        const result = await resp.json();

        // set redis cache
        client.set(username, JSON.stringify(result));
        return res.send(setResponse(username, result));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}


app.get('/repos/:username', cache, getRepos);
```

Comment: Can you expand on 'didn't work'? What kind of problems are you facing?

Comment: @LeoMurillo All the set of commands I listed returned one form of error or the other. I just need a way to store the result of a database query in a redis cache and also be able to update it.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a way around it. The key lies in being able to convert from objects to strings and vice versa where necessary.

```
function setResponse(username, result){
    const val=JSON.stringify({...result});
    return `<h2>${username} has ${val} repos</h2>`
}
```

> ```
> //cache middleware
> function cache(req, res, next){
>     const { username } = req.params;
>
>     client.get(username, (err,data) => {
>         if(err) throw err;
>         if(data !== null){
>             console.log('DATA', typeof data);
>             return res.send(setResponse(username, JSON.parse(data)));
>         }
>         next();
>     })
> }
> ```

```
async function getRepos(req, res, next){
    try{
        console.log('fetching...');
        const { username } = req.params;
        const resp= await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

        const result=await resp.json();
        console.log('RES',typeof result);

        //const repos=data.public_repos;

        // set redis cache
        client.setex(username, 3600, JSON.stringify({...result}));
        return res.send(setResponse(username, result));
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
}

app.get('/repos/:username', cache, getRepos);
```

**N.B: This may not be the best solution to the problem. Other solutions are still welcome.**